# wget -o writes empty files on failure

Tags: wget

If I write 
wget  "no such address" -o "test.html"
it first creates the test.html and in case of failure, leaves it empty.
However, when not using -o, it will wait to see if the download succeeds and only after that, it'll write the file.

I'd like the latter behavior to be applied to -o too, is it possible?

Answer (score 27):

`wget` returns a non-zero exit status when the URL is not found, so you can append a remove command on failure:

```
wget "url" -O file || rm -f file
```

Or create a temporary file and only move it where you want on success:

```
wget "url" -O /tmp/wget && mv /tmp/wget file
```

The second has the benefit of not deleting an existing file on failure, but be sure to use unique temporary names (see `man tempfile`) if you're running multiple instances in parallel.

Comment: Also, adding **--retry-connrefused** can help in preventing the empty file in the first place.

Comment: If this is happening in an **exec** in a puppet manifest, changing **creates => file** to **unless => "[ -s file ]"** can make it self-healing.

Answer (score 19):

As written in the comments, `wget -O` [is more like a shell redirection](http://www.mail-archive.com/wget@sunsite.dk/msg08586.html) which always writes into the file regardless of errors.

You can use `curl -f` instead:

```
curl -f http://nonexistent/file.jpg -o localfile.jpg
```

It will not touch the local file if there is an error fetching the file.

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax is

```
wget "url" -O file
```

notice the UPPERCASE O. The -o options tells wget to write **a log file**, that's why it's always written
even on failure.

Comment: At first I thought it was working, but then I found it didn't.
try 
wget "http://host.does.not.exist" -O "emptyFile"

An error is returned, yet the emptyFile is created.

Comment: @akurtser you're right. I think there's no way to tell wget not to create the file. I found this thread: http://www.mail-archive.com/wget@sunsite.dk/msg08586.html in which they discuss the matter. The baseline is that you can have MULTIPLE downloads to the same file so it gets created because wget cannot be shure that ALL urls will fail.

Comment: Well thanks, it's a part of a bash script I'm writing, so I'll just try to first save it a temp file, which in case of successful download, will be be renamed.
Not very elegant, but can't think of anything better.

Comment: @akurtser Surely you can check the return code from wget then... it should tell you if you can delete the file "if not found". So no need for temp/renaming.

Comment: The -O option is a redirection, which redirects the downloaded content to a file, even in cases when there are no contents. Therefore, a file is always created, even if the download failed.

Comment: Just to be correct: GNU Wget 1.21, The correct syntax is: `wget [OPTION]... [URL] …`

Answer (score 0):

According to the help doc(wget -h), you can use --spider option to skip download(version 1.14).

```
Download:
  -S,  --server-response         print server response.
       --spider                  don't download anything.
```

Comment: So then we use `wget --spider "url" && wget "url" -O file`